# I want to ask the user to put values in and then display total after the end of the week in console in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Write a code to ask the user about the number of letters sent each day of the week and display the total number of letters sent in a week in console in javascript

```js
var day = 1;
var totalletters = 0; //total letters sent


for (day; day <= 7; day++) {
  var getletters = 0;
  getletters = prompt("Please enter the number of total letters sent today", );
  totalletters += getletters;
}

console.log(totalletters); //displaying the total number of letters sent at the end of the week

// The console is showing the output as string instead of adding up the numbers
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `prompt()` returns a string.  Try `totalletters += Number(getletters)`

Answer (score 0):

`prompt()` returns a string; adding strings together concatenates them.

You need to convert the prompt responses into numbers before adding:

```js
var day = 1;
var totalletters = 0; //total letters sent

for (day; day <= 7; day++) {
  // var getletters = 0;   // <-- this is redundant, since you replace the value in the next line
  var getletters = prompt("Please enter the number of total letters sent today", );
  totalletters += Number(getletters);
}
console.log(totalletters);
```

(There are multiple other answers suggesting getting the *length* of the string instead; I think they're interpreting the "total number of letters" as meaning that you want the number of letter (characters) in each input.  You said the "number of letters *sent*" though, so I'm assuming you mean as in postal mail, and want user input of "9" to mean 9, not 1.)

Comment: I understood that he wanted the length of the string.  There’s no need to down it’s my answer, there clearly ambiguity in the question a simple explanation would have sufficed

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you are looking for...

```js
var day=1;
        var totalletters=0;  //total letters sent
        
        
        for(day; day<=7; day++) { 
         getletters=prompt("Please enter the number of total letters sent today",);
         totalletters += getletters.length;
        }
        
        console.log(totalletters); //displaying the total number of letters sent at the end of the week
        
        // The console is showing the output as string instead of adding up the numbers
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take advantage of .length to acquire the length of your prompted string.  This way you can treat it like a number.

The following code works.

Example here: https://jsbin.com/yewaga/edit?js,output

```
var totalletters = 0; //total letters sent
var getletters = 0;

for (var day = 0; day < 7; day++) {
  // noprotect
  getletters = prompt("Please enter the number of total letters sent today");

  totalletters += getletters.length;
  //console.log(totalletters)
}

console.log(totalletters);
```

Comment: That’s what he’s asking for, a way to count all the letters in the string, can be done with length

Comment: I hadn't come to that interpretation of the question's wording, but I see it now. Apologies; my downvote is locked in but I'll remove it if you edit